# $f(x,y) := \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, &\mbox{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0, & \mbox{if } (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$ not differentiable in $(0,0)^T$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$f(x,y) := \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, &\mbox{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
0, & \mbox{if } (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$

I need to show that all partial derivatives in $(0,0)^T$ exist which I already did, but how can I show that $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)^T$?

Comment: maybe you have $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's not even continuous there. See what happens when $x=y$.

Comment: Because $f(1/n,1/n)=1/2 \neq 0$ for example?

Comment: @user556917 Yes, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Making $y = \lambda x$ we have

$$
\frac{x y}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}
$$

then $f(x,y)$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

An easy manner to think is using Change of variables like
    $$ x = R cos \theta $$
and
    $$ y = R sin \theta $$
Try this!